# WP Rocket is making my site to get a white page every time i update pictures or text

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, rocket

So i have Wp rocket on my site and i saw that every time i modify a image or a text from my site, the homepage appears white with only the cookie icon visible.... i have to delete cache each time this happens and also i have to check page every time.. This i what support said but no clue.....

I enabled WP Debug while performing the following test:
I made a small edit (added a dot at the beginning of the content) and saved the settings. I visited the page from desktop and from mobile, but it rendered correctly. I repeated the test by reverting the change I made. Still, the page got rendered correctly.

So far I could not reproduce the issue, but I checked the information provided by Sandy. Based on my observations, the issue is not related to WP Rocket, but I will explain to you why you see it when WP Rocket is enabled.

Generally, when a page is rendered in WordPress your theme is rendering the following parts of the code in the exact order for each page:

1. header.php
2. template (i.e. the content)
3. footer.php

When the issue occurs, the template part is missing. Here is how I found it:

Sandy was able to reproduce the issue in the past and shared the code difference between the blank page and the correctly displayed page. You can find it here: https://www.diffchecker.com/AKBv9sVj/

Here is the place where part of the HTML is missing on the "blank" page. And I highlighted the last line of code that is included in both cache files:

Full-screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHbNb.png

That last line of code comes from header-adora-framework.php which is included with no issues:

Similarly, the next segment that both pages have in common comes from the footer:

Full-screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4e2G.png

This is where the code in footer-adora-framework.php, and it is also included with no issues:

Full-screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0IhJ.png

Based on this, I can see that the template part is missing. It seems your theme is not rendering the template sometimes.

I checked the debug.log that is available on the server and found the following fatal error that might be related to the issue:

Here is the main part of the error: "The template "/wp-content/themes/project-theme/templates/layout.html.php" cannot be rendered."

If you check the file mentioned in the error, you will find that this is exactly the part that is missing:

Full-screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sowA.png

The code from /wp-content/themes/project-theme/templates/layout.html.php:

Full-screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EosLf.png

The reason that you see the issue only when WP Rocket is enabled is due to caching. WP Rocket "takes a snapshot" of the page the way it was rendered the first time it was accessed.
If the template did not render the template part when the page was accessed - this is how the page will be cached and you will see the issue persists.

This, however, does not mean that the issue is resolved when you disable WP Rocket.
The issue is happening, but it is not persistent as with caching. Refreshing the page when caching is not present would likely resolve the problem.

You would need to pass this information on to your theme support. Possibly they will have suggestions on how the problem can be resolved.

I try all but nonthing. I hope to fix this with your help

Comment: Your theme has a “template loader” that might be custom. As noted, I’d contact them and ask about it. The other option is to hack the theme/framework and start putting a bunch of `die` messages around to determine where the failure is occurring.

Comment: What do you mean with "template loader". I know my theme is custom...

Comment: Just literally what it means, something that loads a template. The email includes a reference to “template part”, which implies  the literal, too. There’s also references to the “adora framework” which further implies something more complex, since PHP is a framework, WordPress is a framework, and now there’s a third. I’m not saying right or wrong, just pointing to how I’d personally attack this